# How do I prove that such homomorphism exists?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a part of an argument I'm reading right now, and I don't get this.

> Let $G,H$ be groups.
>
> Let $K\lhd G$ and $N\lhd H$.
>
> Let $\phi:H\rightarrow H/N$ and $\psi:G\rightarrow G/K$ be the canonical homomorphisms.
>
> Let $\Phi:H\rightarrow G$ be an injective homomorphism.
>
> Assume $N\subset \ker(\psi\circ \Phi)$
>
> Then, there exists a homomorphism $f:H/N\rightarrow G/K$ such that $f\circ \phi=\psi\circ\Phi$.

How do I prove that?

The author assumes this is trivial, but it is not trivial to me.. Please help

Comment: This looks extremely messy to me, but I don't even understand how the composition $\;\psi\circ\phi\;$ is possible since $\;\text{Im}\,\phi\rlap{\;\;/}\subset \;\text{Im}\,\psi\;$

Comment: You should try drawing a diagram. Also you have your $\phi$ and $\psi$ switched in your last expression.

Comment: @Cameron I don't get that they are switched.. Domain and codomain meets fine.. I didn't write $\psi\circ \phi$. I wrote $\phi\circ\Phi$.

Comment: Well @Rubertos, it appears "psi" both in the question and in your original draft.

Comment: @Timbuc Oh.. Okay. Since I couldn't see edit history, I thought i didn't make a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you know this more basic fact: If $f \colon H \to G$ is a morphism of groups, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ such that $N \subseteq \ker(f)$, then $f$ factors uniquely as $f = \bar{f} \circ \pi$, where $\bar{f} \colon H/N \to G$ is a morphism and $\pi \colon H \to H/N$ is the projection.

In your situation, you want to apply this lemma with $G$ replaced by $G/K$, and $f$ replaced by $\psi \circ \Phi$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common trick in dealing with quotients. It may feel like "cheating" to some extend since we end up defining our function the way we want it to come out. (I really wish I knew how to use Tikz here so I could include a diagram...) Your function $f$ naturally lives on $G/K$ so it is a function of cosets. Define a seemingly arbitrary function $h(gK) = (\phi\circ\Phi)(g)$. What properties does $h$ have? What is its codomain? Is it well-defined?